# NodeJS application not running on centos

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, node.js

I am trying to run following simple nodejs code. when I open `[IP ADDRESS]:PORT` on browser, After a long loading I get request timeout.

When I try to run code with `node index.js` I get `Server ready` response on command line but no response on browser (request timeout).

index.js file:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080); 
console.log('Server ready');
```

Comment: Did you confirm that your server is running using `netstat -lnp | grep 8080`?

Comment: @Khaled I have request timeout on every port except 80

Comment: Can anybody help ?

Comment: You did not answer my question!  Can you post the output of `netstat -lntp`?

Comment: @Khaled Thanks. The 8080 port was closed. I had to open that and it's working.